# Haskell: Implementing a design with an interface and a polymorphic function

Tags: haskell, interface, polymorphism

Again I'm requesting comments about how a given design should be implemented in Haskell.
Thanks in advance to everyone providing helpful comments. Also I hope this could be an aid to other Haskell novices like me, having a practical sample code.

This time, we have a polymorphic function `doSampling` (in module Samples) that takes a generic function f and
a list of reals (indexes) and returns a `Samples` (indexes, values=f(indexes)). We want implement `doSampling` only once, as it doesn't matter if is f is a `Polynomial` or a `Sinus`. For that,
we have introduced an interface Function, and have Polynomial and Sinus types implement it.
The following is the design being implemented:

[image]

## **Edit 1**:

There is a debate on the `Function` interface (class in Haskell). It has been suggested it is not actually necessary, as `doSampling` may take a "nude" function `(Double -> Double)` instead.
But, **how to do it**, if you *need* some extra state within the nude function  (coeffs for a polynomial, amp+freq+phase for a sinus?

## **Edit 2**:

Very good answers by kosmikus and by Chris Taylor. Thanks.
A key idea in both: have

`doSampling :: (Double -> Double) -> [Double] -> Samples`

This is: it takes a function `(Double -> Double)` (instead of `Function`) and list and returns samples.

My intention was to keep the state of `Polynomial`s and `Sinus`es. That is not regarded in Chris answer, but it is in kosmikus'. On the other hand, the weak point in kosmikus version could be how to extend its `Function` definition if you don't have access to the source code.

I would also point out:

- Chris' idea of encapsulating a polynomial or a sinus into a function `(Double -> Double)` by means of a factory function `mkPolynomial` or `mkSinus` that generates  (using currying?) the desired function taking the apropriate parameters. (Although you can't consult the parameters later).
- kosmikous' idea of using `value` to transform (also using currying?) a `Function` into a `(Double -> Double)`
- Both answers are worth reading as they have other little Haskell tricks to reduce and simplify code.

### In sum

- Chris answers does not support keeping the state of a Polynomial or of a Sinus
- kosmikus answers is not extensible: adding new type of functions (Cosinus ...)
- my answer (being verbose) does overcome the previous downsides, and it would allow (this not necessary for the problem) impose Function types to have more associated-functions apart of `value` (in the sense of how an java-interfaces work).

## **My own approach**

**main (usage)**

```
import Polynomial
import Sinus
import Function
import Samples

-- ...............................................................
p1 = Polynomial [1, 0, 0.5]  -- p(x) =  1 + 0.5x^2 
s1 = Sinus 2 0.5 3 -- f(x) = 2 sin(0.5x + 3) 

-- ...............................................................

-- sample p1 from 0 to 5
m1 = doSampling p1  [0, 0.5 .. 5]
m2 = doSampling s1  [0, 0.5 .. 5]

-- ...............................................................
-- main
-- ...............................................................
main =  do
    putStrLn "Hello"
        print $ value p1 2
        print $ value s1 (pi/2)
        print $ pairs m1
        print $ pairs m2
```

**Function**

```
module Function where    
-- ...............................................................
-- "class type"  : the types belonging to this family of types
--    must implement the following functions:
--          + value : takes a function and a real and returns a real
-- ...............................................................
class Function f where 
    value :: f -> Double -> Double
        -- f is a type variable, this is:
        -- f is a type of the Function "family" not an actual function
```

**Samples**

```
module Samples where

import Function

-- ...............................................................
-- Samples: new data type
-- This is the constructor and says it requieres
-- two list, one for the indexes (xs values) and another
-- for the values ( ys = f (xs) )
-- this constructor should not be used, instead use 
-- the "factory" function: new_Samples that performs some checks
-- ...............................................................
data Samples = Samples { indexes :: [Double] , values :: [Double] }
     deriving (Show)

-- ...............................................................
-- constructor: it checks lists are equal size, and indexes are sorted
new_Samples :: [Double] -> [Double] -> Samples
new_Samples ind val 
             | (length ind) /= (length val) = samplesVoid
             | not $ isSorted ind = samplesVoid
             | otherwise = Samples ind val

-- ...............................................................
-- sample a funcion
-- it takes a funcion f and a list of indexes and returns
-- a Samples calculating the values array as f(indexes)
doSampling :: (Function f) => f -> [Double] -> Samples
doSampling f ind = new_Samples ind vals
              where 
                    vals = [ value f x | x <- ind ]

-- ...............................................................
-- used as "error" in the construction
samplesVoid = Samples [] []

-- ...............................................................
size :: Samples -> Int
size samples = length (indexes samples)   
-- ...............................................................
-- utility function to get a pair (index,value) out of a Samples
pairs :: Samples -> [(Double, Double)]
pairs samples = pairs' (indexes samples) (values samples)

pairs' :: [Double] -> [Double] -> [(Double, Double)]
pairs' [] [] = []
pairs' [i] [v] = [(i,v)]
pairs' (i:is) (v:vs) = (i,v) : pairs' is vs


-- ...............................................................
-- to check whether a list is sorted (<)
isSorted :: (Ord t) => [t] -> Bool
isSorted [] = True
isSorted [e] = True
isSorted (e1:(e2:tail))
         | e1 < e2 = isSorted (e2:tail)
         | otherwise = False
```

**Sinus**

```
module Sinus where

-- ...............................................................
import Function

-- ...............................................................
-- Sinus: new data type
-- This is the constructor and says it requieres
-- a three reals
-- ...............................................................
data Sinus = Sinus { amplitude :: Double, frequency :: Double, phase :: Double }
     deriving (Show)

-- ...............................................................
-- we say that a Sinus is a Function (member of the class Function)
-- and then, how value is implemented
instance Function Sinus where
         value s x = (amplitude s) * sin ( (frequency s)*x + (phase s))
```

**Polynomial**

```
module Polynomial where

-- ...............................................................
import Function

-- ...............................................................
-- Polynomial: new data type
-- This is the constructor and says it requieres
-- a list of coefficients
-- ...............................................................
data Polynomial = Polynomial { coeffs :: [Double] }
     deriving (Show)

-- ...............................................................
degree :: Polynomial -> Int
degree p = length (coeffs p)  - 1

-- ...............................................................
-- we say that a Polynomial is a Function (member of the class Function)
-- and then, how value is implemented
instance Function Polynomial where
         value p x = value' (coeffs p) x 1

--  list of coeffs -> x -> pw (power of x) -> Double
value' :: [Double] -> Double -> Double -> Double
value' (c:[]) _ pw =  c * pw
value' (c:cs) x pw =  (c * pw) + (value' cs x x*pw)
```

Comment: I don't see much benefit in the `Function` class, and certainly not in actually overloading a function such as `doSampling` over the `Function` class. The function `doSampling` could simply be parameterized over a function of type `Double -> Double`. Also, the more normal way would be to model `Function` as a datatype with `Polynomial` and `Sinus` being constructors.

Comment: @kosmikus Yes, I think maybe you are right. It seems unnecessary *here* to have the Function class. Thanks. Why not contribute it as an   answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @kosmikus. Rethinking it, you have to consider that, we don't want doSampling only take a "nude" function (Double->Double) but a type with "extra" state that a bare function doesn't carry (coeffs for a polynomial, amp+freq+pahse for a sinus). So for the moment, I regard  *useful* the `Function` class.

Comment: Wow!  Far too complicated for what your problem seems to be.  Look at Chris Taylor's answer.

Comment: But a function with the "extra" state that you speak of *is* just a "nude" function!

Comment: @augustss Please, see my comments to Chris Taylor's answer.

Comment: You can't design a system in low enough level detail to have a UML class diagram (which is inherently OO), and then pretend it's some sort of abstraction independent of implementation details that is suitable for implementing in any programming language, let alone any programming *paradigm*. You *can* of course "implement this design" in any language, but it will not be an effective way to produce good code, or to learn a new programming language. The truth is you *design* code differently for different languages, which is probably the most important part of learning a new language.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for your opinion, but I greatly disagree. You miss that OO doesn't come out from OO languages, but on the contrary, OO languages were created to better support real world objects that encompasses state and actions over that state. In this regard OO is not an exclusive property of OO languages. I think that the failure is with the fan boys on both sides: everything is an object vs. everything is a function, while "real world" is not pure in any sense. The best approach is be "impure" and take the best of both worlds (like Hanna Montana :-)) ... continuing below ...

Comment: @Ben So what you have to say if I want an object because in my problem domain something is actually an object? I can't use Haskell just because Haskell does not well support objects? I think everyone of us must assume that there is not a perfect language. Finally "you design code differently for different languages" is not a law written in stone. That is so just because the limitations of each language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Expanded my comment on request.]

I'd probably do this roughly as follows:

```
import Data.Functor

-- Use a datatype rather than a class. Yes, this makes it harder to
-- add new types of functions later, and in turn easier to define new
-- operations. ("expression problem")
data Function =
    Sinus { amplitude :: Double, frequency :: Double, phase :: Double }
  | Polynomial { coeffs :: [Double] }
  deriving (Show)

-- Interpreting a Function as an actual function.
value :: Function -> (Double -> Double)
value (Sinus amp freq ph) x = amp * sin (freq * x + ph)
value (Polynomial cs)     x = value' cs x

-- Rewrite value' to not require non-empty lists. This can also be
-- nicely written as a fold.
value' :: [Double] -> Double -> Double
value' []     _ = 0
value' (c:cs) x = c + x * value' cs x

data Samples = Samples { indexes :: [Double] , values :: [Double] }
  deriving (Show)

-- Use Maybe to detect error conditions, instead of strange values
-- such as voidSamples.
newSamples :: [Double] -> [Double] -> Maybe Samples
newSamples ind val 
  | length ind /= length val = Nothing
  | not $ isSorted ind       = Nothing
  | otherwise                = Just (Samples ind val)

doSampling :: (Double -> Double) -> [Double] -> Maybe Samples
doSampling f ind = newSamples ind (map f ind)

isSorted :: (Ord t) => [t] -> Bool
isSorted []  = True
isSorted [e] = True
isSorted (e1:e2:es)
  | e1 < e2   = isSorted (e2:es)
  | otherwise = False

-- This is just zip.
pairs :: Samples -> [(Double, Double)]
pairs (Samples idxs vals) = zip idxs vals

p1 = Polynomial [1, 0, 0.5]  -- p(x) =  1 + 0.5x^2 
s1 = Sinus 2 0.5 3 -- f(x) = 2 sin(0.5x + 3) 

m1 = doSampling (value p1) [0, 0.5 .. 5]
m2 = doSampling (value s1) [0, 0.5 .. 5]

-- The <$> maps over a Maybe.
main =  do
  putStrLn "Hello"
  print $ value p1 2
  print $ value s1 (pi/2)
  print $ pairs <$> m1
  print $ pairs <$> m2
```

Comment: The original object oriented design doesn't call for anything like a `Function` expression. The coefficients of the polynomial and the amplitude, phase and frequency of the sinusoidal are all private, so they aren't expected to be recovered or inspected later. The only thing we're expected to be able to do with a `Function` is evaluate it. That'd be `data Function = Function {value :: Double -> Double}`. We might as well drop the cruft and instead just use `Double -> Double`.

Comment: @Cirdec Yes, I actually agree that the reply by Chris Taylor is even simpler and the way to go. I had looked at the code more than at the diagram and had incorrectly assumed that some later inspection of the function data was desired.

Comment: @kosmikus kosmikus was not wrong. I didn't added more functions/methods to Polynomial and Sinus to keep it simple. But please note that Polynomial has a degree() and Sinus could easily have getFrequency() and getAmplitud() in a *real* scenario. In this case, do you both still regard Chris Taylor answer still better than komsmikus? I don't think so.

Comment: @Cirdec, please see my previous comment. Thanks.

Comment: @kosmikus I don't know if there exists libraries in Haskell in the C/C++ sense: you only have access to the interface (.h) and not to the source code. What if you don't have access to the `data Function ...` definition. How then you can add  new `Function`s like `Cosinus`, `exponential` whatever.?

Comment: @kosmikus By the moment I prefer your solution :-) You share with Chri's answer the idea of `doSampling` getting a real function `(Double -> Double)` but keeping the state of a `Polynomial`, of `Sinus`, etc, so it could be possible to add functions on this types. It is also a good point, having `value` to be a "converter" from `Function` to `(Double -> Double)`!

Comment: @Cirdec we could just put it in a module and not export the data constructors and functions that are supposed to be private. This design would really only be more useful if you wanted to restrict the module to only work on those two kinds of functions as opposed to working with all `Double -> Double` functions, though. The other answer provides a more general approach.

Comment: @cibercitizen1 I think the main point that both Chris and I make is that `doSampling` should work on `Double -> Double` as an argument. As Chris says in his remark, if you want to do additional things with your functions, you might indeed want to have a data representation for them. It depends on the application whether it's better to introduce one datatypes per kind of function (and perhaps a type class), or to introduce a single datatype like I suggest here. The single datatype approach is in particular helpful if you want other "interpretations", e.g. a symbolic evaluator.

Comment: @kosmikus Thanks. I have edited my answer to reflect the key points of both answers. Feel both free to edit it to make any correction you consider. One last think, so not to steal your time. Could you point a link on what you mean by "single datatype"?

Comment: @cibercitizen1 Single datatype means `data Function = Sinus ... | Polynomial`. One datatype per kind of function means `data Sinus = ...` and `data Polynomial = ...`.

Answer (score 12):

You certainly don't need the `Function` class. All this heavyweight class, instance, member variable fluff is one of the things that Haskell is designed to avoid. Pure functions can be much more flexible.

Here's a simple way of doing what you want.

```
type Sample = ([Double], [Double])

newSample xs vs
  | isSorted xs && length xs == length vs = (indices, values)
  | otherwise                             = ([], [])

pairs = uncurry zip

doSampling :: (Double -> Double) -> [Double] -> Sample
doSampling f xs = newSample xs (map f xs)

mkPolynomial :: [Double] -> (Double -> Double)
mkPolynomial coefs x = go coefs
  where
    go  []    = 0
    go (c:cs) = c + x * go cs

mkSinus :: Double -> Double -> Double -> (Double -> Double)
mkSinus amp freq phase x = amp * sin (freq * x + phase)

p1 = mkPolynomial [1, 0, 0.5] -- 1 + 0.5x^2
s1 = mkSinus 2 0.5 3          -- 2 sin(0.5x + 3)

m1 = doSampling p1 [0, 0.5 .. 5]
m2 = doSampling s1 [0, 0.5 .. 5]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ p1 2
  print $ s1 (pi/2)
  print $ pairs m1
  print $ pairs m2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Please, let me try if I understood it. The key point is to use real functions (Double -> Double) to represent just functions (it seems obvious now). You deal with different kind of functions (polynomials, senoidals) just having two "factory functions" that produce a function of the desired type out of its corresponding parameters. Finally, doSamplig just takes a function (Double->Double) and a list of indexes.

Comment: Chris. What if you want have a degree function for polynomials, or a getFrequency for Sinus? Can your solution manage that? How? If not, the what's the way to go? Thanks indeed.

Comment: This solution shows you how to sample general functions over general domains. The functions are *opaque* -- all you can do is evaluate them. If you want to do more with your functions that evaluate them, you will indeed need to carry that information around separately. You could do that by considering the functions as data, or by introducing a type class. However, I would keep that orthogonal from the code for sampling, to give you maximum flexibility.